# columns names not read properly by read.csv in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file whose contents I'm trying to read into R. But my columns names don't get displayed correctly, it shows some weird characters in the name of the first columns.(Please note that this is the case with any csv file that I try to read in)

Please see R code below

```
> mycsvfile = read.csv('C:\\Users\\wdsuser\\Desktop\\mycsvfile.csv')
> mycsvfile
  ï..col1  col2
1   hello world
2   first  last
3     bye   bye
> names(mycsvfile)
[1] "ï..col1" "col2"   
> mycsvfile$col2
[1] world last  bye  
Levels: bye last world
> mycsvfile$col1
NULL
```

This is how my text file looks

```
col1,col2
hello,world
first,last
bye,bye
```

R version :

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2014                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        66913                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet
```

Comment: Not reproducible with the data you provided here: `mycsvfile = read.csv(text = 'col1,col2\nhello,world\nfirst,last\nbye,bye'); names(mycsvfile); # [1] "col1" "col2"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a problem with the encoding:

```
read.csv('C:\\Users\\wdsuser\\Desktop\\mycsvfile.csv', fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
```

should work.

Comment: I encountered the same problem! It is documented in `?read.csv` , redirecting to `?file` in section `encoding`.