# read csv +unicode in R

Tags: r, csv, encoding

I have the same problem as explain in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838613/cannot-read-unicode-csv-into-r) ,the only difference is that the CSV file contain  non_english string and I couldn't find any solution for it : 
when I read the csv file with out encoding it gives me no error but the data changed to :

```
network=read.csv("graph1.csv",header=TRUE)

  Ø§Ø´Ù¾ÛŒÙ„(60*4)
```

and if I run the `read.csv` with `fileEncoding` it gives me this error:

```
 network=read.csv("graph1.csv",fileEncoding="UTF-8",header=TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'graph1.csv'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'graph1.csv'

 network[1]
[1] X.
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

system info :

```
windows server 2008
R:R3.1.2
```

sample file :

```
node1,node2,weight
ورق800*750*6,ورق 1350*1230*6mm,0.600000024
ورق900*1200*6,ورق 1350*1230*6mm,0.600000024
ورق76*173,ورق 1350*1230*6mm,0.600000024
ورق76*345,ورق 1350*1230*6mm,0.600000024
ورق800*200*4,ورق 1350*1230*6mm,0.600000024
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [columns names not read properly by read.csv in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005632/columns-names-not-read-properly-by-read-csv-in-r)

Comment: it just not the columns name the whole file is not reading properly.

Comment: second warning should be solved according to my answer, due to the carriage return you forgot.

Comment: For what it’s worth, the example file works perfectly on Mac (assuming the system locale is set to UTF-8), and both code snippets work – it’s almost certainly a Windows-specific problem, because the Unicode support under R for Windows is quite frankly shabby.

Comment: you should have the below result by putting a EOD delimitor at the end (what I also called carriage return)

Answer (score 2):

I tried with your input this:

```
> read.csv("graph1.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
                      X.U.FEFF.node1                                  node2 weight
1  <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642>800*750*6 <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642> 1350*1230*6mm    0.6
2 <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642>900*1200*6 <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642> 1350*1230*6mm    0.6
3     <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642>76*173 <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642> 1350*1230*6mm    0.6
4     <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642>76*345 <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642> 1350*1230*6mm    0.6
5  <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642>800*200*4 <U+0648><U+0631><U+0642> 1350*1230*6mm    0.6
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but still it gives me the warning `Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'graph1.csv'.` and just the second warning solved and it just read the header file now. `[1] node1  node2  weight
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) `

Comment: can you give a sample of your file?

Comment: The output from the first code doesn’t look like there’s an UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I add some of the data in the question.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel ,thanks . yes without file encoding the file is read as you mentioned

Comment: you can get the encoding by mentionning it but for the title, I will see tomorrow the different fileEncoding/windows options to turn around the headers.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, yes ,I also get this when I use `encoding` instead of `fileEncoding`

Comment: it is the format you need. The only thing is now the headers, you can uset setNames command if needed.

Comment: thanks @ColonelBeauvel, please see the comment of the Rudolph answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work – mind you, I can’t test it since I don’t have Windows (and Windows, Unicode and R simply do not mix):

```
x = read.csv('graph1.csv', fileEncoding = '', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

At this point, `x` is gibberish, since it was read as-is, without parsing the byte data into an encoding. We should be able to verify this:

```
Encoding(x[1, 1])
# [1] "unknown"
```

Now we tell R to treat it as UTF-8:

```
x = as.data.frame(lapply(x, iconv, from = 'UTF-8', to = 'UTF-8),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

These two steps can be compressed into one by using `encoding` instead of `fileEncoding` as the argument to `read.csv`:

```
x = read.csv('graph1.csv', encoding = 'UTF-8', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

In either case, roughly the same process takes place.

At this point, `x` *still* appears as gibberish, since your terminal on Windows presumably does not support a Unicode code page which R understands. In fact, when running the code with a non-UTF-8 code page on Mac, I get the following output now:

```
x[1, 1]
# [1] "<U+0648><U+0631><U+0642>800*750*6"
```

However, at least the encoding is now correctly set, and the bytes are parsed:

```
Encoding(x[1, 1])
# [1] "UTF-8"
```

And if you pass the data to a device or program which speaks UTF-8, it should appear correctly. For instance, using the data as labels in a `plot` command should work.

```
plot.new()
text(0.5, seq(0, 1, along.with = x[, 1]), x[, 1])
```

[image: plot output]

Comment: thansk for the explanation, but after some analysis I need to write the data back to csv , but now I by just writing the file after `x = read.csv('graph1.csv', encoding = 'UTF-8', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)`. I will get the out put as it is in here, encoding not the real data.

Comment: @academic.user Unfortunately at this point my lack of access to Windows prevents me from trying out what might work. But have you tried just writing the file? The data hasn’t been changed at all, so this might work.

Comment: .thanks, yes I tried `write.csv(network, file = "network.csv",row.names=FALSE)` after `network=read.csv("graph1.csv", encoding="UTF-8", header=TRUE)` and the output is :`"X.U.FEFF.node1","node2","weight"
"<U+0648><U+0631><U+0642>800*750*6","<U+0648><U+0631><U+0642> 1350*1230*6mm",0.600000024
"<U+0648><U+0631><U+0642>900*1200*6","<U+0648><U+0631><U+0642> 1350*1230*6mm",0.600000024 `